# Can anyone explain the strange Object behavior of getBoundingClientRect()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you test the following example you'll notice that the console does not log the correct coordinates, `.onmouseover` of the box. I know I'm getting the `cb` Object before the `.onmouseover`, but usually when you access a DOM Object property it gives you the correct value at the time.

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box'), cb = box.getBoundingClientRect();
box.style.margin = '30px';
box.onmousemove = function(e){
  console.log('x:'+(e.clientX-cb.left)+'; y:'+(e.clientY-cb.top));
}
```

```css
#box{
  width:160px; height:90px; background:#700;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'></div>
```

Notice this way works:

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.style.margin = '30px';
box.onmousemove = function(e){
  var cb = box.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log('x:'+(e.clientX-cb.left)+'; y:'+(e.clientY-cb.top));
}
```

```css
#box{
  width:160px; height:90px; background:#700;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'></div>
```

Well, it should work, oddly `x` never seems to hit `0`, either *(of course I know I can do the math)*. Is there any valid reason for any of the behavior I've described? I'm using FireFox 69.0.3 (64-bit). Is it a bug? I have a work around. I'm just asking.

Comment: Works the same way in Chrome 75 on Windows 10. I think it's because in the first instance you assign `cb` *before* you add the margin to the element, which then throws off the calculations. If you move `var cb = box.getBoundingClientRect();` outside the function but after `box.style.margin = '30px';` then the result is the same as the second snippet.

Comment: If I open a browser `console` I can see `x` do get `0`

Comment: @SatyamPathak for the first piece of code?

Comment: I'm sure `@SatyamPathak` means the second. I'm just getting 1 for x as my lowest value.

Comment: Yep Sorry, It's the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply because a DOMRect is not live. That's just like a plain object that get created every time you call one of the methods that return such an object; and even if the originating Element is modified, the DOMRect will still just be whatever it was when it got created.

```js
const target = document.getElementById( 'target' );

const rect_1 = target.getBoundingClientRect();
target.style.width = '120px';
const rect_2 = target.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log( rect_1.width, rect_2.width ); // 10, 120
```

```css
#target { width: 10px }
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Comment: I guess I'll accept this as the answer, that it's "not live". I can see from a technological standpoint that they would do this to limit executions, since each property would require the getter to be executed. It just seems strange. Glad to know it's not a bug. I just didn't see any documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that in the first instance you take `cb` *before* adding the margin.

Since [`getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) will give you the positions *at the point of time it was called*, you get a snapshot of the positions without a 30px offset. That's why both `x` and `y` never go below `30` in the first example but they do in the second when you get a fresh snapshot of the positions every time.

If you you can get a reliable snapshot once, then the calculation would be correct:

```js
var box = document.getElementById('box');
box.style.margin = '30px';
var cb = box.getBoundingClientRect();
box.onmousemove = function(e){
  console.log('x:'+(e.clientX-cb.left)+'; y:'+(e.clientY-cb.top));
}
```

```css
#box{
  width:160px; height:90px; background:#700;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not asking what the issue is. Just why they do it like that.

Comment: Why is the DOMRect not re-calculated? I don't think I can answer that other than "it's what the specs say". I can *guess* that it's going to be expensive keeping all potential DOMRect objects in-sync with changes to the DOM when in the majority of cases, you won't need that or you *actively* want the opposite. Also I think it's simpler to make the DOMRect static and require re-making to keep it up to date, than make it live and have to handle the case where the developer wants it to not change. But I'm not equipped to answer what was the actual design reasoning behind this.